# Reference request: Langevin Dynamics

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process, optimal-transport

I'm interested in understanding papers on sampling from a probability distribution via Langevin dynamics as for example:

- [Sampling from a log-concave distribution with Projected Langevin Monte Carlo](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02564.pdf)
- [Sampling as optimization in the space of measures: The Langevin dynamics as a composite optimization problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08089.pdf)
- [Non-asymptotic convergence analysis for the Unadjusted Langevin Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05021.pdf)

I have a strong background in PDE (at the level of Hörmander's, Lion and Magenes' books, etc) and I also went through a couple of advanced classes in stochastic processes but I'm quite rusty now.

What would be good books or lecture notes for getting a good grasp on these papers?
I've seen many books on Markov processes or Log-Sobolev inequality but they look geared towards other more theoretical directions which I don't really care, or they look good as a references
but not so pedagogical.

Comment: Actually, with a strong PDE background and a couple of advanced classes in stochastic processes one should be able to follow these articles. Where do you feel lost?